# Configuring the Tensorflow

Tags: configuration, tensorflow

i followed the installation procedure for tensorflow but i am stuck up somewhere . its when i tried to configure the system . i read your previous answer on same question but in my case , the folder usr/local.lib is also empty. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/configure you answer was also not understandable to me. please guide in simple way how to get out of this installation thing

Comment: Which operating system you are using? Have you tried steps listed on https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html ?

Comment: linux yes i did

Comment: Can you please describe what the problem is? Are you getting any error code?

Comment: You can also list down the commands you tried. That might be helpful.